# Firebase security rules wildcard in get function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am struggling with an issue that is seemingly easy at first glance yet still does not work after trying dozens of different syntaxes. I've got a firebase database with a collection called users and every user has a subcollection 'posts'. What I want to achieve with implementing security rules is that one's posts can only be read by oneself if the account is private or by everyone if the account is public. Therefore, each user has got a boolean field isPublic. Sounds simple. This is my code:

```
match /users/{uid}{
    function isPublic(){
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(uid)).data.isPublic;
    }

    allow read, write: if request.auth.uid==uid

    match /posts/{postid}{
    allow read: if request.auth.uid==uid || isPublic();
}
```

The error is in line 3. If I hard code the uid (currently, I've got just 2 users) of user 2, who is public, and try to open his posts as user 1, it works fine. However, using the wildcard throws an exception every time.

```
return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(uid)).data.isPublic; //does not work

return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/uid).data.isPublic; //does not work

let userid = uid;
return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userid)).data.isPublic; //does not work

let userid = string(uid);
return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userid)).data.isPublic; //does not work

return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/ogfTdmsSG4dy2AHf8dp7LcPpd9B3).data.isPublic; //works
```

I would really appreciate I someone could tell me what the correct syntax is. Thank you very much in advance!

**EDIT**

The associated query that fails is:

```
_database.userCollection.document(idOfUser2).collection('posts').getDocuments();
```

It works fine when logged in as user 2 with security rules activated, and it works fine without security rules no matter of which user is making the request, but fails when user 1 is making the request with security rules activated.

Additionally, I should mention that if I use another function instead of get (for example, in line 5, like this:), it works fine as well.

```
allow read, write: if request.auth.uid==uid|| resource.data.isPublic
```

Thus, I came to the conclusion that the get command does not work. However, I need the get command as resource does not work in subcollections.

Comment: Rules by themselves are not enough to understand what's wrong.  Please edit the question to show the client query that isn't working the way you expect with these rules.  Your question should contain enough information that anyone can reproduce the problem.

Comment: What data do you have in Firestore? Which user is making the request?

Comment: @DougStevenson I've updated my post. Do you know what I mean now?

Comment: I would expect what you have now to work.  Without seeing all the exact values of the variables from your code, and reference that to screenshots of data that show a match, there's not much we can do.  So, be certain that `idOfUser2` contains the value you expect, and verify that the document for that user contains what you expect.